# Error of java script in admin menu and frontend pages

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

On my Wordpress website no plugins are working. For example in my admin panel I have errors in console, look at the screenshot. And on the frontend jQuery files aren't working. It begun after I transferred the website from one domain to another. But after transfer, I have changed all URLs to the correct.[image]

Answer (score 0):

Make backups obviously, but you might want to checkout Velvet Blues (plugin) to see if it's a reference to a resource coming from within the database.

If that's not working try moving to a different theme and seeing if the problem persists. I don't see how this could be an issue from only changing a domain name.